# How to run a "foreach" loop on elements with comma separated attribute values?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, foreach

I am trying to compare the values of two elements, and if they share that value, execute a .css() modifier upon one of them. The issue is that some of my comparing elements have values in a comma separated list:
normal values: "400", "500"
comma'd values "600, 602" "502, 504"

My jQuery is as follows:

`jQuery('#container1 > div[booth-number="{Booth Assignments}"]').css('background-color','white')`

as you can see I'm using a merge tag to indicate the booths that i'd like to have their background color modified with.

I was also trying something like a forEach loop:

```
const booths = [{Booth Assignments}]
booths.forEach(jQuery('container1 > div[booth-number=jQuery(this)]').css('background-color', 'white')
```

which does not seem to work either. could really use some help here!

Answer (score 1):

First, you can take the array and join it with a comma, replace the spaces, then split it on the comma. This will allow you to loop through the items.

Next, I'm using a data attribute since booth-number isn't valid.

Since you are using jquery, I'm also just using **$.each**

```js
let booths = ["600, 602", "502, 504"].join(",").replace(/[\s]/g, "").split(",");

$.each(booths,function(index,booth) {
  $('#container1 > div[data-booth-number="' + booth + '"]').css('background-color', 'red')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container1">
  <div data-booth-number="600">608</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't catch the caveat of the CSV + array requirement. Nice job.

Comment: This works great in a static setting! however, i'm using a forms plugin that stores these potential strings. they are then stored and summoned conditionally in a DataTable. so, now upon a search query, my dev console gets filled with about 100 "booths is already defined. I'm now trying to nest it in a promise that upon resolving unsets that variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your foreach syntax is incorrect.

```js
const booths = ["this", "is", "dummy", "data", "and,some,more", "dummier,datas"].join(",").replace(/[\s]/g, "").split(",");
console.log("All booths: ");
console.log(booths);
console.log(" ");  // Blank line for readability

booths.forEach(function(booth_number) {
     $('container1 > div[booth-number=' + booth_number + ']').css('background-color', 'white');
     console.log("This should color booth \"" + booth_number + "\" white.");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```